# Recursion to dynamic programming

Tags: java, programming-challenge, recursion, mathematics, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve a problem on *de-arrangements* (Number of partial derangement such that exactly  prime number discs are found away from their natural positions? (Any number of non-prime K disks may also be found in or out of their natural positions)).

Somehow solved it using recursion but my code fails (taking long time to show output sometimes it gets freezes) on larger inputs for parameter **move** like **(1000, 1000000)**, working fine for smaller inputs. Any approach to optimize this recursive function with Dynamic Programming with better time complexity.

```java
static BigDecimal derangements(int move, int dontCare) {

        if (move < 1)
            return factorial(dontCare);

        // recursion
        move--;
        BigDecimal result = derangements(move, dontCare).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(dontCare));
        if (move > 0) {
            result = (derangements(move - 1, dontCare + 1).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(move))).add(result);
        }

        return result;
}
```

I tried something like this but failed to correctly implement it. I know it's wrong. Any correct approach or implementation would do.

> ```
> static BigDecimal derangements(int move, int dontCare) {
>   BigDecimal[] moveResult = new BigDecimal[move + 1];
>
>   moveResult[0] = factorial(dontCare);
>
>   for (int i = 1; i < move; i++) {
>       moveResult[i] = moveResult[i - 1].multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(dontCare));
>   }
>
>   while ( move  > 1) {
>       int i = 1;
>       moveResult[i] = moveResult[i - 1].multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(dontCare))
>
>               .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(move)).add(moveResult[i]);
>       move--;
>       i++;
>   }
>
>   return moveResult[move-1];
> }
> ```

Comment: If your code fails to do what's intended, it's not ready for code review here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ taking long time to show output sometimes it gets freezes

Comment: Also note that [cross-posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57938401/recursion-to-dynamic-programming) is frowned upon in the SE network.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ help me to solve this I will remove one of the post.

Comment: At least here your question seems to be _off-topic_. We're not going to provide you with working code. I am not that sure that you'll get better results at Stack Overflow, unless you put some more efforts in debugging and profiling the code in question. Generally SE sites aren't meant as personal help desks.

Comment: I completely disagree @πάνταῥεῖ. The code works for small inputs. OP is looking to improve their code by making it handle large inputs.

Comment: @RubberDuck Let's agree to disagree ;-).

Comment: I’ve nominated this question to be reopened and edited the question to put the broken code in a quote block as context for the review on the code that does work.

Comment: @RubberDuck Please someone  help me with the code

Comment: @RubberDuck I found two meta posts about this scenario: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/are-questions-about-performance-on-topic and https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/should-we-close-improve-performance-for-unfriendly-numbers-problem. However, slow code, vs app fails/freezes, I'm not sure how to deem this question...